# loading "explicit" iptables rules on boot or interface up

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I'd like to load iptables rules on boot or interface going up on Ubuntu. Made a search on StackExchange and other places and looks like the most commonly agreed approach is either use `iptables-save`/`iptables-restore` or `iptables-persistent` package. I'd prefer (may be due to my not yet matured Linux nature) to keep iptables rules in "explicit" form (e.g. `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`) instead of having all different rules dumped into the same persistent file where, without comments and some structure, could be tricky to find a particular rule and change it.

What I did so far - I've added following line to the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
post-up         sh -c "/etc/iptables/eth0.post-up.sh"
```

where `eth0.post-up.sh` is a file where iptables are explicitly set (e.g. `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`). All would be good, rules are applied, but the reason I'm writing here is that if I try to run `iptables -L FORWARD` then I don't see the loaded rules, though I'm sure they are applied (it's a subnet forwarding rules and I see that ping goes through when the rule has run and that it doesn't when the rule hasn't run. Here is the output:

```
# iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

If I comment out the above post-up ... in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file (making sure the rules are not applied) and then run the rules manually I get the output:

```
# iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

So, the rules are applied in both cases, but in the former case then `iptables -L` doesn't show the rules, and in later ase it does.

Ultimately it works but I'd like to understand what's the caveat here, why it looks like I'm the only one around who is trying to use this approach, and why `iptables -L` doesn't give me expected output.

UPDATE: have to correct myself, not all iptables rules in `eth0.post-up.sh` file are executed, out of 3 commands below:

```
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

only the last one (wiht POSTROUTING) is executed which is required for ping to go through, where as the first two neither have any traces in the `iptables -Lnv FORWARD` nor result in connection getting established (e.g. `wget google.com`) from another computer which uses this box as a router. But if I run this file manually after boot - then all is executed correctly, both ping and wget from remote computer work as expected.

Comment: Is that script executable? Why not simply `sh "/etc/iptables/eth0.post-up.sh"`?

Comment: Yes, the script is executable, so I've changed to as you suggested - and the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use softether vpn on my pi. I use [this](https://gist.github.com/martakus/343b83406e545523ed8d) gist to set it up.

Softether (or at least this script) puts iptable rules in /etc/rc.local

As an example, this is mine

```
 # Start VPN Settings

 for vpn in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*; do echo 0         > $vpn/accept_redirects; echo 0 > $vpn/      send_redirects; done
 iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

 # End VPN Settings

 exit 0
```

This should run your iptable commands on boot. May be a more appropriate way, but this seems to work for me (at least as far as vpn concerned, never had any issues)

Just make sure you put tables before

```
 exit 0
```

Comment: geoffmcc, thank you, will try this approach on ubuntu - there is no rc.local in it, but I assume rc.x should be similar

Comment: I have it both on 14.04 and 14.10, but I'm running servers. I am at work so can't check my desktop running 14.10 to see if has `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: geoffmcc, I tried your approach and it works, thank you, all rule, FORWARD and POSTROUTING added on boot. It's strange that if I try to run these rules via script in /etc/network/interfaces with post-up or via /etc/init/iptables.conf then only POSTROUTINGs are applied, FORWARDs are ignored (though am sure there is a good reason for this). Anyway, rc.local works for me and I stop here. I assume I should be able to mark your answer as the answer, but somehow cannot find how to do it, may be I don't have enough vote-power.